# Refreshing a window from another thread while other operations are performed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have been trying to keep the splash screen for my application from hanging while the application loads its initial data, however I have not yet been sucessful in finding a way to do this.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
SplashView splashScreen = new SplashView();
            new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    while ((bool)splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke((Func<SplashView, bool>)delegate(SplashView sView) { return sView.IsEnabled; }, DispatcherPriority.Render, new object[] { splashScreen }))
                    {
                        splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action<SplashView>)delegate(SplashView sView) { sView.UpdateLayout(); }, DispatcherPriority.Render, new object[] { splashScreen });
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }, DispatcherPriority.Render, new object[] { });
            }).Start();
```

Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load all your data (model / view models) on background thread (like `BackgroundWorker`).
2. `Dispatcher.Invoke()` will hang your UI thread as multiple invokes would block due to synchronous execution of code. Use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` instead. It uses the dispatcher queue more effectively.
3. Use `DispatcherPriority` to your advantage. Any Splash UI notifications which are of lower importance could be displayed following higher priority ones.
4. Use `Dispatcher.PushFrames()` if you want to notify Splash for something on priority.
5. Split your data loading in multltiple background threads and use `Wait` / `Pulse` to notify others when the slower ones finish. Unrelated data can be loaded in different threads e.g. Finance related data and employee related data can be loaded using different threads.

Comment: I can't do the loading in seperate threads due to it populating observable collections with data, which are not multi-threaded, also can you give me some examples maybe?

Comment: Observable Collections cause thread access issue only if they are bound to the items control already and thrad safe observable collection already exist (although they are not actually multi threaded) http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2007/04/22/Thread-safe-observable-collection.aspx .... Also there are lot of examples on web about WPF Splash Screen loading e.g. This example uses `PushFrames()` http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFsplashscreen.aspx .... This example uses multi threading with Pulse / Wait using `AutoResetEvent` ... http://szymonrozga.net/blog/?p=136.

Comment: That post on making the ObservableCollection thread safe was very helpful thank you!